# Before COVID, what was the largest aviation crisis ever?

Tags: commercial-aviation, aviation-history, economics

The Covid-19 pandemic is the worst crisis aviation has ever faced. Which one was the biggest one before that pandemic?

Comment: could you define "biggest"?

Comment: @Federico, w.r.t. impact, e.g. airplanes grounded, airliners struggling, employees getting laid off, passengers afraid to fly, and so on. I exclude World Wars periods.

Comment: I'm not sure the Covid-19 pandemic is a crisis to _aviation_. Most certainly it is to the airline industry, but to aviation as a whole? Really? My father has flown his Cub weekly all summer.

Comment: To commercial aviation I meant @CGCampbell.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crisis is somewhat hard to define explicitly but the [September 11th Attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/September_11_attacks) had an [enormous impact on the commercial aviation](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/13571510500127931?scroll=top&needAccess=true&) industry in perhaps more ways than the current Pandemic has.

[It took nearly 3 years for aviation travel numbers to return](https://www.bts.gov/archive/publications/special_reports_and_issue_briefs/issue_briefs/number_13/entire) after the attacks and arguably we are still seeing lasting impacts on changes to broad aviation travel procedures as a direct results of the attacks even 20 years later.

Comment: Probably the right answer, maybe I was too young back then, thanks.

Comment: I am skeptical.  Surely the closure of routes and repurposing of personnel, aircraft, and production lines during World War II was a bigger (as a proportion) and longer lasting change, even if aviation was much smaller then.

Comment: This was asked a couple months ago.

Comment: @JohnK let's close it as a dupe then!

Comment: @AnonymousPhysicist I would believe the opposite to be true. The world didn't have many commercial aviation planes or routes prior to WWII. WWII itself advanced the knowledge and equipment of flying to such a great extent that I am a firm believer that if WWII hadn't happened, aviation as we know it would have been at least a decade longer in happening.

Answer (score 2):

[Hindenburg disaster](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindenburg_disaster) may be a candidate. This fire firmly ended the era of the Zeppelins and other great airships filled up with hydrogen that were flying transatlantic routes at that time. Helium filled airships, even if much less flammable, somehow shared the decline as well.

The aviation needed to switching into very different fixed wing aircraft, using technologies developed during WWII.

Comment: Ah very interesting answer as well, thanks!